# How to execute a shell command in a SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite, shell

I've looked for a function to execute a shell command in a SQLite query, e.g., a function `exec()` that would execute the given command.

Is there such function in SQLite?

Comment: For the complete function list in SQLITE refer [This LiNK](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html) and for exec() refer [this LINK](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html). I hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: But this is a C-interface? Could I not execute the shell command from plain SQL?

Answer (score 3):

When you are inside SQLite shell, you can execute any shell command using the ".shell" command without exiting out of the SQLite shell. For example:

```
.shell echo "Hi there!"
```

prints the greeting (using OS's echo command) and continues to stay inside the SQLite shell.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is designed for small embedded systems, which might not even have a shell.
So there is no `exec()` among the [built-in functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

However, it would be easy to create your own [user-defined function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to wrap the `system()` C function.

Comment: So, I cannot have the SQLite execute commands like nslookup like it is possible for MS SQL Server through use of EXECUTE()?

Comment: Is there a function then that allows writing to a file? I'd like to create a trigger that will "push" new rows to a pipe with a process listening on the other side. Sort f like messaging queue. This would awesome

Comment: @TheRealChx101 There is no built-in function for that. (Again, the shell [has a user-defined function](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#file_i_o_functions).)

Comment: @TheRealChx101: I use this extention: https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/fileio.c. This works like a charme, If you remove the SQLITE_DIRECTONLY flag in the call of sqlite3_create_function (in fileio.c) which creates the writfile() function you can use it even in triggers.